# How to count occurrences of a column value efficiently in SQL Without repetition?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

While finding count, I'm getting count as:

```
Serial No  |   Countt
------------------------
10467      |     1
10468      |     1
10468      |     2
10469      |     1
```

I want to query for finding count as follows:

```
Serial No  |  Countt
----------------------
10467      |     1
10468      |     2
10469      |     1
```

And I used below Query:

```sql
(SELECT Distinct Tax_Percentage, Serial_No, 
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Tax_Percentage,Serial_No ) AS Countt
FROM sales_detail Where Serial_No>=10467)
Order By  Serial_No
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to Find Count As I Needed.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id, attribute, COUNT(attribute) FROM mytable GROUP BY attribute

[This can help you](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/176860/count-multiple-occurences-of-attribute-values-for-each-row-in-sql)

Comment: Mustafa --- .Thank you for the Answer.I have tried it.But its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Group by the two columns

```
SELECT Tax_Percentage, Serial_No, COUNT(*) Countt 
FROM sales_detail 
Where Serial_No>=10467) 
Group by Tax_Percentage, Serial_No
Order By Serial_No
```

I am not sure what you wat to achieve but if you want to finde the occurences of serial_no you need to partition the count by this column.

```
SELECT Tax_Percentage, Serial_No, 
        COUNT(*) over(partition by Serial_No) Countt 
FROM sales_detail 
Where Serial_No>=10467) 
Order By Serial_No
```

Comment: @Manfred.Thank you for the Answer.I have tried it.But its not working.But It Produce the Same Result –

Comment: I am not sure if I understood what you want to achieve, but I tried to adapt the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This: Because of Taxpercent you know we cant get unique, if you skip that column you will get easily:

```
SELECT distinct TaxPrcnt,SrNo,count(CAST(ISNULL(SrNo,0) as int)) OVER(PARTITION BY SrNo 
ORDER BY SrNo) AS Countt
FROM #temp
```

[image]

Comment: i hope it is okay for you in current scenario.